# VisualGDB. Expression must have pointer type

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, android-ndk

I have just started using visualgdb

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int s_ButtonPressCounter = 0;

jstring
Java_com_visualgdb_example_AndroidProject1_AndroidProject1_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    char szBuf[512];
    sprintf(szBuf, "You have pressed this huge button %d times", s_ButtonPressCounter++);
    jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, szBuf);
    return str;
}
```

I have my intelissense show error log 
Expression must have pointer type.

I tried to change it to env.NewStringUTF(szBuf) but the build comes to error.

Comment: Use `snprintf` so you don't overflow the `szBuf`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you should replace

```
jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, szBuf);
```

with

```
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF(env, szBuf);
```

or with

```
jstring str = (*env).NewStringUTF(env, szBuf);
```